# WordPress шаблон cactus, задний фон :hover

Tags: css, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем  нужно, чтобы в шапке, при наведении на ссылки, на заднем фоне появлялся серый фон (как будто выделилась кнопка), я игрался CSS `:hover`, увеличивал отступы, но задний фон увеличивался (сервы квадрат увеличивался) но текст начал смещаться при наведении.....

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо делать `hover` на `#top-menu a`, при этом дав ему нужный `padding` для подсветки. Размер `#top-menu li` надо уменьшить на размер `padding`, чтобы общий размер `nav` не изменился.

**UPDATE**

Ну или задайте

```
#top-menu a {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: #top-menu a:hover {
 padding-left: 20; 
}
 не сработало... и .cactus-main-header  ничего не меняется

Comment: Да что за сказки - я проверял в инспекторе. padding надо ставить на сам a, без hover. Росно так и написано в моем ответе.

Comment: #top-menu a { 
 padding: 20;
} 
#top-menu li {
 padding: 20;
}
 Не сработало =(((

Comment: да не то делаете опять. дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо, #top-menu a { padding: 20px; } сработало вот только нижнее подчеркивание уплыло

Comment: Ну я же не могу за вас верстать ваш сайт. Я вам дал направление. Дальше сами. Тем более, что такие понятия как "уплыло" не описывают проблему. Задайте новый вопрос, покажите то, что есть, и **точно** опишите желаемый результат.

Comment: hover стал таким как надо. Но сдвинулось всё на постоянной основе, увеличились отступы между словами и нижнее подчеркивание стало шире и ниже (где заканчивается hover фон) (которое я задавал  border-bottom: 1px solid #021e7f;
  line-height: 20px;)..  надо чтобы до наведения выглядило так же как на мои скриншотах выше (всё выравнено и нижнее подчеркивание) а когда наводишь (выравнивание и нижнее подчеркивание остается на месте) а задний сервый фон  hover остался  такой какой сейчас получился